# Lazy loading with Entity Framework error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have created an `.EDMX` file from my database using Entity Framework 6.1.3. Now my code is not compiling with error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a
>   delegate type.

`FEED_DETAIL` is not compiling as I have in `MASTER_FEED` class as:

```
public virtual ICollection<FEED_DETAIL> FEED_DETAIL { get; set; }

public MASTER_FEED GetMasterFeed(string strSnapshotId)
{
    IList<MASTER_FEED> data=_objDbContext.MASTER_FEED.Include(rw =>rw.FEED_DETAIL).Where(x => x.MAST_SNAPSHOT_RECORD_ID.Equals(strSnapshotId));

    return null;
}
```

Any help please.

Comment: Probably error occurs where you call `GetMasterFeed` method. not it ?

Comment: @tchelidze, when I am trying to create a function GetMasterFeed and providing body with above code.

Comment: try adding `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: thanks @tchelidze...it works :)

Comment: Glad if it helped. Please mark my answer as accepted ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```